# Problem with reading csv to python(DictReader)

Tags: python

I want to put the content of a csv file into dictionaries in python. I need to use them in python with functions in classes, so I have to get individual people from the dictionaries. I only need to read the csv file once, put them into seperate dictionaries and go from there. I got this code but I have no idea how to work with it;
import csv

```
file = 'FakeNameSet.csv'
with open(file,  encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
    Customer_list = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in Customer_list:
        print(row)
```

fakenameset.csv is a file formatted like this;

```
Number,Gender,NameSet,GivenName,Surname,StreetAddress,ZipCode,City,EmailAddress,Username,TelephoneNumber
1,male,Dutch,Hisham,Altink,"Borkelsedijk 53","5571 GA",Bergeijk,HishamAltink@teleworm.us,Reech1950,06-16898224
2,female,Dutch,Maren,Breider,"Van Humboldtstraat 130","3514 GS",Utrecht,MarenBreider@dayrep.com,Othed1997,06-23093526
3,male,Dutch,Hayati,"van Dekken","Schorweg 101","5993 PC",Maasbree,HayativanDekken@teleworm.us,Drem1996,06-74004784
```

and the code above gives this output;

```
OrderedDict([('Number', '1'), ('Gender', 'male'), ('NameSet', 'Dutch'), ('GivenName', 'Hisham'), ('Surname', 'Altink'), ('StreetAddress', 'Borkelsedijk 53'), ('ZipCode', '5571 GA'), ('City', 'Bergeijk'), ('EmailAddress', 'HishamAltink@teleworm.us'), ('Username', 'Reech1950'), ('TelephoneNumber', '06-16898224')])
```

It returns OrderedDict's but I have no idea what they are and how to read from it, how to get individual lines or even the names from the tuples.

Comment: Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: If you have no idea what something is, read the docs. They're there exactly to teach people how to use the language.

Answer (score 1):

Each line is being returned as it's own OrderedDict as [described in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=dictreader#csv.DictReader).

You would need to store each of these somewhere to access them or process line by line.

You access them as such (from docs):

```py
>>> import csv
>>> with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...         print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
...
Eric Idle
John Cleese

>>> print(row)
OrderedDict([('first_name', 'John'), ('last_name', 'Cleese')])
```

So you can either do what you want to do line by line instead of `print(row['column_name'])` or you can store them into a list or nest them into another dictionary by a "primary key" such as `number` in your example:

```py
>>> import csv
>>> data = {}
>>> with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...         data[row['Number']] = row
>>> data[1]['GivenName']
Hisham
```